# PHP stdClass Object arrays [_]=> syntax

Tags: php

I am trying to access the 1st part of the following Object.

I'm unable to figure out what is the `[_] =>` syntax?

If I try to print the 1st past of the Object using `Body->[_]` it errors out.

```
[Body] => stdClass Object
(
    [_] => http://xyz.com
http://MPQ.com

    [BodyType] => Text
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$object->_
```

`_` is a valid variable name in PHP.